# Attempted to update mesa drivers-now cannot play games-tried to revert to og drivers and still no luck

Tags: amdgpu, gpu-driver, mesa

Firstly i am fairly new to linux. I had my system running no hitches/glitches at all - playing games no trouble through Steam.

Secondly, I attempted to update my graphics drivers recently and now I am unable to launch any game successfully.

I tried to follow this guide https://itsfoss.com/install-mesa-ubuntu/ (not bleeding edge).

After 'installing' it appeared to work however;  'glixinfo | grep Mesa' didn't show that a newer driver version (still Mesa 21.1.0)

I've tried DX11, DX12 and vulkan games, proton and linux native games.

I then attempted to purge the Kisak repo and roll back however I still can't run any games. I can get to desktop - I notice now that when i logon, the original logon wallpaper pops up for a micro second, and sometimes the icons won't be there (although that seems to be ok today so could be unrelated). I also tried to install update vulkan no luck either.

i'm on the most recent xubuntu LTS - cpu-x states Linux 5.11.0-37 generic / Ubunutu 20.04.2 LTS. Hardware is new 5000 series amd cpu and 6000 series gpu. (note that on occassion I will boot a win10togo on an external ssd).

Any assistance would be appreciated. Moving forward I will likely be trying these things on a spare usb before on the main rig.

Thanks

Russ

[edit have re-tried the process - crusader kings 3, csgo, valheim launch however sotr and everything else in my library do not]

Comment: You can install `ppa-purge` and then run it against the PPA - `sudo ppa-purge ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa`. Theoretically this should get you back exactly to the starting point by removing the PPA and everything that was installed from it. Now, if you did something else in your attempts then all bets are off.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks for the response - I did the purge and attempted reinstalling kisak and tried oibaf repos -  I (with the assistance of a highly experienced linux user) were unable to get the mesa drivers working original or new. However, as a last resort before reinstalling we tried the amdpro drivers and it is working fine again (and now with the bonus of amd ray tracing).

Comment: You should post that as an answer (that you can accept latter, of course, and get points) and a warning. Many users often recommend those PPAs blindly. And add that the often unnecessary proprietary overlay `amdgpu-pro` in your case worked towards your goal with an added bonus.

Answer (score 0):

I did the purge and attempted reinstalling kisak and tried oibaf repos - I (with the assistance of a highly experienced linux user) were unable to get the mesa drivers working original or new. However, as a last resort before reinstalling we tried the amdpro drivers and it is working fine again (and now with the bonus of amd ray tracing).

So while I couldn't solve the problem behind the mesa drivers my system is at least working with the amdgpu-pro drivers and may be worth considering if you are having the same issue.